# Problem on finding angle of straight line with $Z$ axis and validity of using vector.

Tags: geometry, vectors

> If a straight line makes an angle of $60^{\circ}$ with each of the $X$ and $Y$ axes,  what is the angle of the line with the $Z$ axis?

**MY WORK:**

I assumed a vector $a\hat{i}+b\hat{j}+c\hat{k}$ which meets the above criteria  . Now,  from property of dot product,  I get:
         $$\frac{a}{ \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

and  $$\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Again  , $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

So,  from dot product of the Z component :

$$\cos^2\theta_z=\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$
$$=2\times \frac{1}{4}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

So  , $$\theta_z=45^{\circ}$$

And the answer is correct. **Is it valid to use a vector?**  But I cannot understand it geometrically.  I mean, it is from a chapter of straight lines. But I did not use any straight line properties. I think that'll be lengthy.  **Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is indeed good: in space you can write the equation of a straight line with only a point and a vector called the **direction vector**. Your problem doesn't ask for a specific line so, with only the direction vector, you've generated a set of parallel lines which all satisfy your requirement on the angles.

For completness, the parametric equation of a line crossing a point $P(x_p,y_p,z_p)$ with direction vector $\vec{v}=(a,b,c)$ is: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}x=x_p+at\\y=y_p+bt\\z=z_p+ct\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: How do I include angles in there or work with them?

Comment: You could do it in the same manner as you did in your question: the vector $\vec{v} = a\hat{i}+b\hat{j}+c\hat{k}$ is your direction vector for the line